# How to convert RASA base Text bot to Rasa base Voice Bot

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I already inserted the value for the RASA NLU using text format but I want insert that value using voice command. I already create google voice to text file to get the text out put. But I didn't understand how to move that text value into my Rasa NLU. I am using Rasa Open Source.

Comment: Hi, could you please describe with which step you are struggling? Is it the part where you connect Google Voice to Rasa? Maybe this blog article helps you https://blog.rasa.com/going-beyond-hey-google-building-a-rasa-powered-google-assistant/

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what exactly you're doing without the code. But since you say that you get the text output, you can use it as a message sent to rasa `Agent`:

```
from rasa.core.agent import Agent
from rasa.utils.endpoints import EndpointConfig

async def chat(message):
    agent = Agent.load("/path/to/your/model")
    respond = await agent.handle_text(message)
    return respond

asyncio.run(chat("hi"))
```